# Wix 3.9 add the pre-reuitsites for my installer

Tags: wix, wix3.9

I want to add the prerequisites for my installer, I successfully added .net framework as prerequisites, but I wanted to add "k-lite codec pack" before installing my actual application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle>
     <Chain>
      <ExePackage
              SourceFile="..\Redist\KLite_Codec_Pack_1090_Full.exe"
              DetectCondition="ExeDetectedVariable"
              InstallCommand="/verysilent /ACTION=Install"
              RepairCommand="/verysilent ACTION=Repair /hideconsole"
              UninstallCommand="/verysilent ACTION=Uninstall /hideconsole"
              Compressed="yes"
              Permanent="yes"/>
     </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

The above code solves my problem. by the installCommand /verysilent will install the klite pack silently.